# I have a data in column A update every minute. I have to transfer each cell data after one minute in new column than create trend

Tags: excel, vba

Everything working fine up to 64 rows than it stop transferring data.

```
 Option Explicit
    Public dTime As Date
    ;Main program
    Sub ValueStore ()
    Dim dTime As Date
        Range("B" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A1").Value
        Range("c" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A2").Value
        Range("D" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A3").Value
        Range("E" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A4").Value
        Range("F" & Cells(Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Range("A5").Value

        Call StartTimer
    End Sub
```

First button for start

```
Sub StartTimer()
    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05") !here i tack 5 sec
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
End Sub
```

Second button for stop

```
Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: ; First button for start
        Sub Start`enter code here`Timer()
            dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")  !here i tack 5 sec
            Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=True
        End Sub
        ;Second button for stop
        Sub StopTimer()
            On Error Resume Next
            Application.OnTime dTime, "ValueStore", Schedule:=False
        End Sub

Answer (score 0):

`Cells(Rows.Count).Row` is 64 in modern versions of Excel files.  That is because `Rows.Count` will be 1048576, and therefore `Cells(1048576)` is referring to cell `XFD64` which is on row 64.  Your code needed to specify a column so that it looked at the 1048576th cell in one column.

```
Option Explicit
Public dTime As Date
;Main program
Sub ValueStore ()
    Dim dTime As Date
    Dim nextRow As Long
    'Calculate the row number once
    nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("B" & nextRow).Value = Range("A1").Value
    Range("c" & nextRow).Value = Range("A2").Value
    Range("D" & nextRow).Value = Range("A3").Value
    Range("E" & nextRow).Value = Range("A4").Value
    Range("F" & nextRow).Value = Range("A5").Value

    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: One more thing. I want to show this data in chart but chart must flexible select range of data.....

Comment: @YATIN - that is completely different to the original question, so please raise a new question.  (Someone in the future who wants to know how to add a chart to a sheet is not likely to expect to find the answer in a question titled "I have a data in column A update every minute. I have to transfer each cell data after one minute in new column than create trend".)  P.S.  Some people will refuse to answer questions if they see that you don't "accept" answers to previous questions.  So, if my answer helped you, please click the "tick" that should appear to the left-hand side of the question.)

Comment: Thanks dear. I have ask a new question. but in above case i have transfer data from protected sheet every minute which is software updated. After 4-5 data data transfer i got error "run time error 1004".

Comment: Thanks dear. I have ask a new question. but in above case i have transfer data from protected sheet every minute which is software updated. After 4-5 data data transfer i got error "run time error 1004". The cell or chart you are trying to change is protected and therefore read only. Even after i unprotected the file. I received the same error.