# VBA: Checking if every headers is fine in range

Tags: excel, vba

Hello guys I'm getting started in VBA and want to check if every header of my range is in good position. So 1st position will be: "Dana wartosc" 2nd: "a" etc But the problem is that in every loop it's taking me to else (which means that the header is bad) and I can't see why, because when I'm checking for example `RangeHolder(1)` by `Debug.Print RangeHolder(1)` in code it's showing me proper value.

Can you tell me what I'm missing?

What I want is when it's checking in switch 1st header. The message is saying that 1st header is fine and it's checking each header in loop

[image]

```
Option Explicit
    Sub Szukanka()
        Dim UpRow As Integer, DownRow As Integer, RangeHolder As Range
        Dim x
        x = 1
        UpRow = 1
        DownRow = 5
        Set RangeHolder = Range(Cells(UpRow, 1), Cells(DownRow, 4))
        RangeHolder.Select

        For x = 1 To 4
            Select Case RangeHolder(x)
            Case RangeHolder(1) = "Dana wartosc"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case RangeHolder(2) = "a"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case RangeHolder(3) = "b"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case RangeHolder(4) = "c"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case Else
                MsgBox ("Its bad" + RangeHolder(x))
            End Select
        Next x
    End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, can you post a screen-shot of your `RangeHolder` ? that we can see the `Range` you are looking for the headers ?

Comment: Your `Select Case` statement is comparing several boolean expressions (e.g. `RangeHolder(1) = "Dana wartosc"`) against the value of `RangeHolder(x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Select Case` statement has been written incorrectly, and you should also be treating `RangeHolder` as a two-dimensional (rows x columns) object.  (Treating it as one-dimensional won't cause an error, but is unlikely to be what you are trying to do.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43524019/6535336) for a situation where it confused another user.)

```
Option Explicit
Sub Szukanka()
    Dim UpRow As Integer, DownRow As Integer, RangeHolder As Range
    Dim x
    x = 1
    UpRow = 1
    DownRow = 5
    Set RangeHolder = Range(Cells(UpRow, 1), Cells(DownRow, 4))

    Dim Good As Boolean
    For x = 1 To 4
        Good = False
        Select Case RangeHolder(1, x).Value
            Case "Dana wartosc"
                Good = x = 1
            Case "a"
                Good = x = 2
            Case "b"
                Good = x = 3
            Case "c"
                Good = x = 4
        End Select
        If Good Then
            MsgBox "It's good"
        Else
            MsgBox "It's bad " & RangeHolder(1, x)
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

I have tried to write the `Select Case` above to do what I think you were trying to do (i.e. check the first row to make sure it had the correct values as headers?).  However, that really doesn't lend itself to a `Select Case` structure, and you would be better off writing it as an `If` statement

```
Option Explicit
Sub Szukanka()
    Dim UpRow As Integer, DownRow As Integer, RangeHolder As Range
    Dim x
    x = 1
    UpRow = 1
    DownRow = 5
    Set RangeHolder = Range(Cells(UpRow, 1), Cells(DownRow, 4))

    Dim CorrectValues As Variant
    CorrectValues = Array("Dana wartosc", "a", "b", "c")
    For x = 1 To 4
        If RangeHolder(1, x).Value = CorrectValues(x - 1) Then
            MsgBox "It's good"
        Else
            MsgBox "It's bad " & RangeHolder(1, x)
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

---

**The reason why your `Select Case` wasn't working:**

If your original `Select Case` statement was rewritten as the equivalent block `If` statement, it would have looked like this:

```
If RangeHolder(x) = (RangeHolder(1) = "Dana wartosc") Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
ElseIf RangeHolder(x) = (RangeHolder(2) = "a") Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
ElseIf RangeHolder(x) = (RangeHolder(3) = "b") Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
ElseIf RangeHolder(x) = (RangeHolder(4) = "c") Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
Else
    MsgBox ("Its bad" + RangeHolder(x))
End If
```

If the value of `RangeHolder(x)` was `"a"` (and `RangeHolder(1)` was `"Dana wartosc"`, `RangeHolder(2)` was `"a"`, `RangeHolder(3)` was `"b"`, and `RangeHolder(4)` was `"c"`) that then becomes:

```
If "a" = True Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
ElseIf "a" = True Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
ElseIf "a" = True Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
ElseIf "a" = True Then
    MsgBox ("Its good")
Else
    MsgBox ("Its bad" + "a")
End If
```

As `"a"` is not = `True` (it would actually give a Type Mismatch if written like this, but wouldn't in a `Select Case` syntax) then the `Else` expression would be invoked.

Comment: Nice, again work was in my way, but love your answer

Comment: Happy again to see some arrays ;) in the second part (+1), which is similar to mine and posted at the same instance. Only thing It's probably preferable that the array is created only once at the beginning.

Comment: @A.S.H - Got to keep you happy - created a Variant variable to store the correct values.  Stole your variable name - please don't blame me for plagiarism.  (I capitalised the first letter so I could say it was different ;) )

Answer (score 1):

The select statement is wrongly written and moreover the overral method is not a good approach, because it results in a poorly readable code. Remove all from the line `RangeHolder.Select` and replace it with this, so that your correct values appear in the code in a readble and oredered manner:

```
    Dim correctValues: correctValues = Array("", _
        "Dana wartosc", "a", "b", "c") '<-- write correct sequence here
    For x = 1 To UBound(correctValues)
        If RangeHolder(x) <> correctValues(x) Then
            msgBox (RangeHolder(x) & " is not at the correct position :(")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next x
    msgBox "All is good :) "
End Sub
```

Comment: Even nicer :) Didn't even think of this approach

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax has flaws. Please try this:-

```
Sub Szukanka()
    Dim UpRow As Long, DownRow As Long       ' rows and columns are generally Longs
    Dim RangeHolder As Range
    Dim x As Long                            ' it's a column, right?

    x = 1
    UpRow = 1
    DownRow = 5
    Set RangeHolder = Range(Cells(UpRow, 1), Cells(UpRow, 4))
'    RangeHolder.Select                      ' don't need to select anything

    For x = 1 To 4
        Select Case RangeHolder(x).Value
            Case "Dana wartosc"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case "a"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case "b"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case "c"
                MsgBox ("Its good")
            Case Else
                MsgBox ("Its bad" + RangeHolder(x))
        End Select
    Next x
End Sub
```